# VBA error on debug option

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i'm new in VBA can you please explain why my debug.print give error?
Thank you

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

i = Worksheets.Count
Set ws = Worksheets(i)

Debug.Print ws



End Sub
```

Comment: what property of ws are you interested in? You can't print the actual worksheet object

Comment: you are probably looking for the sheet's name, so try `Debug.Print ws.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print the worksheet object (ws). You can print some of it's properties e.g. it's name. Also, put Option Explicit at the top of your module and declare i.

You can use Debug.Print to write out information, to help with debugging, to the immediate window.  The immediate window can be opened with Ctrl + G.

You can gain the same information by putting ? in the immediate window before the same code line e.g. ?ws.Name    (provided your code has been halted during execution, example, with STOP keyword, and has retained the required value)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

i = Worksheets.Count
Set ws = Worksheets(i)

Debug.Print ws.Name


End Sub
```

Comment: LOL, typed it in at the same second

Comment: :-) OMG.... for once, I shall just savour this moment, I got answer in before The Rado! You must have been multi-tasking!

Comment: @QHarr So how debug.print even work how should i use it? And ty for answer

Comment: And this gives much more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716276(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Hopefully that helps

Comment: @Qharr Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Qharr :D yeah it did . Well it is the color as it should be :)

Comment: :-)))))))) jeje

Comment: @QHarr Sorry to bother more but i want to ask for some pointers about python, i noticed that you have some experience in it. But again don't want to bother.

Comment: Depends.... there are lots of python wizards out there and I only occasionally dabble..is it a new question?

Comment: @QHarr Yes like good start for beginer, about sintax, can i use python for large datasets, how hard is to learn (C++ is hard for begginer).

Comment: Python can be used with large datasets, it is pretty easy to learn (at least to get to an intermediate level. Way easier than C++). Syntax: Python has tons of documentation online depending on which version you are using e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: @Qharr wow that site is so f-ing helpfull much more that sites i have found thank you very much. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You will find the best documentation after this will be the actual package documentation as well. Though can be a bit dense. For example if working with Scikit learn you would go to http://scikit-learn.org/  . I topped this up with coursera courses and the like and learning python the hard way.

Comment: @Qharr Thank you :)

Comment: Learning Python the Hard Way being a book :-) It's like marmite to some people :-)

Comment: Depends on your goal. I think it is a worthwhile language. Pick the language according to your requirements.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for your time :) please don't delete any of your comments i would like o save the sites when i get home :)